# How to make matrix operations in field P in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, matrix

I want to perform matrix operations in Ruby in some finite field (say P). What is the best method to do that. Is there a way to use the existing functions such as **, *, + etc applicable on my matrix without manually writing them?

Also is there a way to perform: **A=A%P** (A is the matrix and P is a prime number), without actually going through each element individually and taking module?

Comment: Please clarify your question, not all of us are as up-to-date with mathematics as you are. Do you just want to do basic operations on matrices, such as addition and multiplication? You can do that simply by using for-loops, or you can even bundle those operations by redefining `+` and `*` for your own custom matrix objects. Also, what is the operation `A = A % P`? Is that supposed to be A equal to A modulo P?

Comment: Can't it been done on integers?

Comment: @Alice Matrix in real maths is different from how it gets represented in a programming language. Operations on matrix come from maths but their implementations has to be as per the rules of programming language. If you want A=A%P, then you have to take each element of matrix which is possible through using array, indexing and iteration. Everything is not ready-made.

Comment: @AlokAnand There is a class for handling matrices in Ruby. I don't think that is the problem. The problem is that the OP mentioned field, but did not make it clear what elements it has, and why it cannot be done on integers.

Comment: @sawa yes the matrix has integer elements

Comment: @AlokAnand A=A%P implies that each element of matrix A has been moduled by P

Comment: @Alice Then why did you generalize it to fields instead of writing integers?

Comment: @AlokAnand Sorry, I confused the OP and your comment.

Comment: @sawa it's ok, it happens with everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you had to generalize to matrices on some field where you just have matrices on integer.

You can use `Matrix#map` to easily define a method.

```
require "matrix"

class Matrix
  def % d; map{|e| e % d} end
end

Matrix[[1, 2], [3, 4]] % 3
# => Matrix[[1, 2], [0, 1]]
```

Comment: @sawa also is there a method to exponentiate A such that the resultant matrix I get has all elements moduled by P. If I try exponentiating and then finally moduling, the numbers grow too big, and this slows down everything to a great extent.

Comment: @sawa I am currently trying exponentiation by repeated squaring, but this will work slower than the one provided by ruby library, if I could find a workaround that module thing.

Comment: @Alice if you exponentiate and module a matrix by same number say 3, it is just better to get module of matrix as both operations' result would be the same.

Comment: @sawa: Drat, of course! I short-circuited. It's Marc Andre! That "Andrew" in the name got me!

Comment: @sawa, I have been very tired recently, and in my mind, I confused the name of Marc-Andre Lafortune with the name Andrew Marshall. I was thinking about  Marc-Andre, but I said "Andrew Marshall".